# setcookie wont work with header redirect?

Tags: php, cookies, xampp

I'm trying to set a cookie and using header redirect . but cookie not setting . I have tried `print_r($_COOKIE)`. So, I'm sure that cookie is not setting in that place?

```
setcookie("re",$re);

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Did you see a Set-Cookie header in the response?

Comment: Why are you sending someone back to the referer? Is the referer on the same (sub)domain? You cannot read the cookie from another sub domain. Are you getting any errors ? Have you tried also doing at the top `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','1');`

Comment: Redireting to refferer is always dangerous

Comment: i have tried url instead of referer, no problem with redirecting. but my problem is not redirecting. i just need to set cookie and then redirect.

Comment: I realize error_reporting and ini_set won't do much as you won't see the notice before being redirected. Try this in stead: `setcookie("re",$re) or die ("couldn't set cookie. Headers probably already sent.";` And tell me if you see the message ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the the path I order to make it available within all domain...

As per document

```
The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. 
If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. 
If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ 
 directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. 
The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.
```

try this

```
 <?php
  setcookie("re",$re,0,'/');
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

NOTE : referer should be from your domain